# how to ssh into ubuntu while on windows, having a dual boot system?

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a dual boot system, windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04

Is there anyway to ssh into my ubuntu while I am on windows?

Comment: No, there isn't. Perhaps you're looking for a virtual machine instead?

Answer (score 3):

**Impossible on a dual-boot system**. If one OS is operating, the other cannot be.

- An automobile can have only one driver at any particular time; computer hardware can have only one active Operating System at any particular time.

If you want two Operating Systems to be active at the same time, one must be *virtualized* (which is different than dual-boot). Look into "Virtual Machines" and how they work.